# Expression must be an L value

Tags: c++, variables, include, int, lvalue

I'm trying to make a formula that can identify a right triangle. I'm having some problems with "a" and the = sign.

Error 1: '='; left operand must be l-value.
Error 2: "a". Expression must be a modifiable lvalue.

Any help?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

 using namespace std; 


int main()
{
    int a; 
    int b;
    int c;
    cout << "Input value for A." << endl; 
    cin >> a; 
    cout << "Input value for B. " << endl; 
    cin >> b; 
    cout << "Input value for C. " << endl; 
    cin >> c; 

    a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 = c ^ 2; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `a ^ 2 + b ^ 2` isn't an assignable expression, what's so hard to understand about this fact?

Comment: What do you expect to accomplish by writing " a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 = c ^ 2;"? This is obviously wrong, but without an explanation of what you expect to accomplish here, no answer will be possible. Besides, did you know that `^` is an exclusive-or operator in C++, and not an exponent?

Comment: If you are testing equality use ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` operator is used to get bit-wise XOR in C++.
You should do it in following way:

instead of `a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 = c ^ 2` statement, write a block like:

```
    if(pow(c, 2) == pow(a, 2) + pow(b, 2))
        std :: cout << "true";
    else
        std :: cout << "false";
```